# vkCreateDebugReportCallback EXT not linking, but every other functions in vulkan.h works perfectly

Tags: visual-studio, linker, vulkan

So I have been trying to learn Vulkan lately, and while trying to get the validation layers to work, I got error LNK2019:

```
1>Renderer.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT referenced in function "private: void __cdecl Renderer::_InitDebug(void)" (?_InitDebug@Renderer@@AEAAXXZ)
```

Now the odd thing is that every other function in vulkan.h works perfectly.

I have vulkan-1.lib linked, and I run the AMD implementation of vulkan. The library is from the Vulkan SDK.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The debugging functions from debug_report_ext are not part of the Vulkan core. You need to dynamically load them from the instance via vkGetInstanceProcAddr after making sure that it's actually supported:

```
PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT CreateDebugReportCallback = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
CreateDebugReportCallback = (PFN_vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, "vkCreateDebugReportCallbackEXT");
```

See [my Vulkan debugging helper unit](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/base/VulkanDebug.cpp) for details.

Comment: The link is broken.