# What is the difference between static and dynamic liniking of Vulkan and how differs the role of vkGetInstanceProcAddress?

Tags: vulkan

As I already went through some basic Vulkan tutorials I encountered both possibilities for linink Vulkan - static (using vulkan-1.lib/a) and dynamic (using vulkan-1.dll/so), the tutorials usually stated that there is no difference between these two possibilities, but is it really like this?

The things for me started to be really messy when I have to go through some Nvidia examples and using their way of extension loading and somehow incorporate this to mine application (as i need their Display extension support) - it seems now that application is now linking with both - .dll and .lib. I do not think this is good and I am trying to eradicate this, but for me it revealed some stuff I am not completely sure if I understand correctly, namely:

- What is the difference in usage of vkGetInstanceProcAddr for dynamic and static linking?

I tought that I need to call this function in case I want access Vulkan api function calls and it will provide me function pointers through the dispatch tree to ICD. But why I need to call it another time to get access to some extension functions (e.g. validation layers), but some extension function calls like VkSurfaceKHR or VkSwapchianKHR extension's methods do not need to be accessed through extra call of vkGetInstanceProcAddr, why is it so, and what I am missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing vulkan symbols from standard linux vulkan library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463410/missing-vulkan-symbols-from-standard-linux-vulkan-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are dynamic\runtime linking. The `*.lib` is just a stub implementation that does the dll linking for you, which is not something specific to Vulkan, but something the Visual C++ compiler offers.

The official loader with the "static linking" loads the core commands and the basic native WSI extension and leaves rest unloaded\unexported. Using the `*.dll` directly means you need to load the dll in OS-specific way, and then extract `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` in OS-specific way, and then load everything you need with the `vkGetInstanceProcAddr`.

You can read more at [LoaderAndLayerInterface.md](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader/blob/master/loader/LoaderAndLayerInterface.md#application-interface-to-the-loader).

Comment: So there is no static linking in LunarG SDK Loader anymore? And the vulkan-1.lib is just classic VC++ dll importing lib if I understand it correct way, yes?

Comment: @CJ_Notned Indeed. There's no `*.a`, and the `*.lib` is the conventional VC++ dll stub.