# Vulkan extension function vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR is undefined

Tags: c++, vulkan

My renderer project fails to build. I am trying to add the device extension for push descriptor sets. Any help or point in the appropriate direction is appreciated. I am directly linking using CMake. I am using Vulkan 1.3 specification.

I get the error:

> undefined reference to 'vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR'

I have added the appropriate Extension name to my list of Device extensions.

```
const std::vector<const char*> DeviceExtensions = {
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_PUSH_DESCRIPTOR_EXTENSION_NAME
};
```

The documentation says it has VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties_2 as a dependency. I have added it like so:

```
instance_extensions.push_back(VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME);
```

Looking at Sascha Willems Vulkan samples I saw he added an empty VkPhysicalDevicePushDescriptorPropertiesKHR struct to the pNext member of VkPhysicalDeviceProperties2KHR struct.

```
VkPhysicalDevicePushDescriptorPropertiesKHR pushDescriptorProperties{};
pushDescriptorProperties.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PUSH_DESCRIPTOR_PROPERTIES_KHR;

m_physicalDeviceProperties.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2;
m_physicalDeviceProperties.pNext = &pushDescriptorProperties;

vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties2(PhysDevice, &m_physicalDeviceProperties);
```

UPDATE:

If I uncomment the below line, I will get the error that expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

```
// vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR = (PFN_vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR)vkGetDeviceProcAddr(m_device, "vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR");
```

I am directly linking against vulkan. Is there no way to set these function pointers without ***'#define VK_NO_PROTOTYPES'*** ?

Comment: see https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/master/examples/pushdescriptors/pushdescriptors.cpp#L293

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I am directly linking. If try using vkGetDeviceProcAddr it will tell me vkCmdPushDescriptorSetsKHR is not an lvalue. Is there no way to set these extension function pointers outside of indirect linking?

Comment: I don't think the libraries define symbols for the extensions, you have to dynamically load them, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463410/missing-vulkan-symbols-from-standard-linux-vulkan-library

Comment: If you're not using the [sdk](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home) it might make your life easier

Comment: Yes, I am trying to figure out how to do that without getting rid of all definitions with the VK_NO_PROTOTYPES definition.  It seems like the function is delcared as it autocompletes and shows the arguments it needs. It's not defined and when I try to define it, I get an "expression is not a modifiable lvalue" error.

Comment: have you declared a `vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR` variable? Otherwise you'll be attempting to modify a function which isn't possible

Comment: Yes, but then I get a redefinition error. So are you saying the only way to use extensions is with indirect linking?

Comment: you really should use the vulkan SDK, I think it does all of this for you, otherwise make sure you're copying the example exactly

Comment: I am using the SDK. To be certain I just re-went through the whole process of installing. Same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so as for my findings, the reason the above direct linked vulkan project doesn't work is that the extension '**VK_KHR_push_descriptor**' hasn't been promoted to Vulkan specification yet. There's just no way to '***vkCmdPushDescriptorSet***' function pointer directly. My solution currently is to stick the '***vkCmdPushDescriptorSetKHR***' function pointer into a "vk_ext" (could be any name of course) namespace and assign with ***vkGetDeviceProcAddr***. If it ever does get promoted, I'll just remove from the namespace.

If you want to use '***vkCmdPushDescriptor***' function pointer as is, as of right now, the only way I know of doing it, is by indirect linking. *The Vulkan Cookbook* by Packt goes into how to do this using the "**VK_NO_PROTOTYPES**" definition. Doing it this way, however, will require you to use ***vkGetInstanceProcAddr*** and ***vkGetDeviceProcAddr*** to retrieve all funtion pointers for all functions.