# How to call vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK from Vulkan library?

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, vulkan, moltenvk

I try to create a small app based on **Vulkan v1.3.275.0** (and **MoltenVK** driver for macOS).

I successfully bundle my app into `*.app` with recommended Vulkan structure for macOS. My app opens a window using **[metal-cpp](https://developer.apple.com/metal/cpp/)** library and creates a Vulkan instance using MoltenVK driver.

However, now I need to create a surface for Vulkan device and here I hit troubles.

As I got to create a surface on macOS, I need to call `vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK()` ([ref](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK.html)) from `#include <vulkan/vulkan_macos.h>` but when I try to include this header my app crashes with errors:

```
[build] /Projects/my/third-party/vulkan/include/vulkan/vulkan_macos.h:26:9: error: unknown type name 'VkFlags'
[build] typedef VkFlags VkMacOSSurfaceCreateFlagsMVK;
[build]         ^
[build] /Projects/my/third-party/vulkan/include/vulkan/vulkan_macos.h:28:5: error: unknown type name 'VkStructureType'
[build]     VkStructureType                 sType;
[build]     ^
[build] /Projects/my/third-party/vulkan/include/vulkan/vulkan_macos.h:34:19: error: unknown type name 'VKAPI_PTR'
[build] typedef VkResult (VKAPI_PTR *PFN_vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK)(VkInstance instance, const VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkSurfaceKHR* pSurface);
[build]                   ^
[build] /Projects/my/third-party/vulkan/include/vulkan/vulkan_macos.h:34:59: error: unknown type name 'VkInstance'
[build] typedef VkResult (VKAPI_PTR *PFN_vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK)(VkInstance instance, const VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkSurfaceKHR* pSurface);
```

And if to open this header there are really no declarations or other includes for these types:

```
#ifndef VULKAN_MACOS_H_
#define VULKAN_MACOS_H_ 1

/*
** Copyright 2015-2024 The Khronos Group Inc.
**
** SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
*/

/*
** This header is generated from the Khronos Vulkan XML API Registry.
**
*/


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif



// VK_MVK_macos_surface is a preprocessor guard. Do not pass it to API calls.
#define VK_MVK_macos_surface 1
#define VK_MVK_MACOS_SURFACE_SPEC_VERSION 3
#define VK_MVK_MACOS_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME "VK_MVK_macos_surface"
typedef VkFlags VkMacOSSurfaceCreateFlagsMVK;
typedef struct VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK {
    VkStructureType                 sType;
    const void*                     pNext;
    VkMacOSSurfaceCreateFlagsMVK    flags;
    const void*                     pView;
} VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK;

typedef VkResult (VKAPI_PTR *PFN_vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK)(VkInstance instance, const VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK* pCreateInfo, const VkAllocationCallbacks* pAllocator, VkSurfaceKHR* pSurface);

#ifndef VK_NO_PROTOTYPES
VKAPI_ATTR VkResult VKAPI_CALL vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK(
    VkInstance                                  instance,
    const VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK*          pCreateInfo,
    const VkAllocationCallbacks*                pAllocator,
    VkSurfaceKHR*                               pSurface);
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

I found yet one header `<vulkan/vulkan_metal.h>` but it didn't help too.

What's a right way to create a Metal surface for Vulkan on macOS?

**P.S.** I know there are `GLFW` and similar libraries but I just want to dig into clean Cocoa and Vulkan (MoltenVK) to understand how to connect them manually.

**P.P.S.** I am not sure if it's right to call AppKit, MetalKit and other frameworks a part of Cocoa, fix me if I am wrong.

Comment: As all Vulkan extension functions, these functions have to get loaded dynamically using `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` / `vkGetDeviceProcAddr`. [Dupe candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900051/vkcreatedebugreportcallback-ext-not-linking-but-every-other-functions-in-vulkan). Finally, you have to `#include <vulkan/vulkan_core.h>` before any platform-specific header (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438182/vulkan-win32-h-is-not-recognized/75553820#75553820). Or just `#include<vulkan/vulkan.h>` which will do it for you.

Comment: @Erel, thank you for explanation!  I will try with `<vulkan/vulkan_core.h>`.

Comment: Maybe you could update your answer to explain it's the combination of the two answers mentioned in the question I linked?

Comment: @Erel, can you post your comments as the answer, please, to I could mark it as an accepted solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the combination of the two following questions and their answers (one of them being mine):

- [vkCreateDebugReportCallback EXT not linking, but every other functions in vulkan.h works perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900051/vkcreatedebugreportcallback-ext-not-linking-but-every-other-functions-in-vulkan)
- [vulkan_win32.h is not "recognized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438182/vulkan-win32-h-is-not-recognized/75553820#75553820)

### TL;DR:

- As for all Vulkan extensions, function pointers must be loaded dynamically using [`vkGetInstanceProcAddr`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkGetInstanceProcAddr.html) or [`vkGetDeviceProcAddr`](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/vkGetDeviceProcAddr.html). Note that you will need to specify the corresponding extensions upon instance creation in `VkInstanceCreateInfo::ppEnabledExtensionNames`. You can also use some libraries like [`Volk`](https://github.com/zeux/volk/tree/master) that exist for this purpose.
- Headers such as `vulkan_metal.h` or `vulkan_win32.h` and their siblings require the contents of `vulkan_core.h`, that must be included **before** it. Though the `vulkan.h` header does this for you (provided you added the correct `#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_XXX`), it also `#include`s potentially-heavy platform-specific headers, such as `<windows.h>` on Windows, or `<X11/Xlib.h>` on Linux with X11. This isn't good for compile times. As far as I know, a few forward-declaration suffice, so you may build your own `vulkan.h` that may look like this instead:

```cpp
#ifndef YOUR_VULKAN_H
#define YOUR_VULKAN_H

#include <vulkan/vulkan_core.h>

#if defined(VK_USE_PLATFORM_XXXX)

// Some forward declarations

#include <vulkan/the_platform_header.h>

#endif // #if defined(VK_USE_PLATFORM_XXXX)

#endif // YOUR_VULKAN_H
```

Note: this is what [`Volk`](https://github.com/zeux/volk/tree/master) [does](https://github.com/zeux/volk/blob/master/volk.h).

Answer (score 0):

Researching a GLFW's source code I've finally got how to call `vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK(...)`.

1. We need to turn on one from two extensions (it depends on version):

   ```
    #define VK_EXT_METAL_SURFACE_NAME "VK_EXT_metal_surface"
    #define VK_MVK_MACOS_SURFACE_NAME "VK_MVK_macos_surface"

    std::vector<const char*> ext_names = {
        VK_KHR_GET_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_PROPERTIES_2_EXTENSION_NAME,
        VK_EXT_METAL_SURFACE_NAME,
        VK_MVK_MACOS_SURFACE_NAME,
        // VK_KHR_PORTABILITY_ENUMERATION_EXTENSION_NAME,
    };

    // initialize the VkInstanceCreateInfo structure
    VkInstanceCreateInfo inst_info = {};
    inst_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    inst_info.pNext = NULL;
    inst_info.flags = VK_INSTANCE_CREATE_ENUMERATE_PORTABILITY_BIT_KHR;
    inst_info.pApplicationInfo = &app_info;
    inst_info.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(ext_names.size());;
    inst_info.ppEnabledExtensionNames = ext_names.data();
    inst_info.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    inst_info.ppEnabledLayerNames = NULL;
   ```
2. Need to define prototypes for functions from these extensions:

   ```
    // A little changed code of GLFW
    typedef VkFlags VkMacOSSurfaceCreateFlagsMVK;
    typedef VkFlags VkMetalSurfaceCreateFlagsEXT;

    typedef struct VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK
    {
        VkStructureType                 sType;
        const void*                     pNext;
        VkMacOSSurfaceCreateFlagsMVK    flags;
        const void*                     pView;
    } VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK;

    typedef struct VkMetalSurfaceCreateInfoEXT
    {
        VkStructureType                 sType;
        const void*                     pNext;
        VkMetalSurfaceCreateFlagsEXT    flags;
        const void*                     pLayer;
    } VkMetalSurfaceCreateInfoEXT;

    typedef VkResult (*PFN_vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK)(VkInstance, const VkMacOSSurfaceCreateInfoMVK*, const VkAllocationCallbacks*, VkSurfaceKHR*);
    typedef VkResult (*PFN_vkCreateMetalSurfaceEXT)(VkInstance, const VkMetalSurfaceCreateInfoEXT*, const VkAllocationCallbacks*, VkSurfaceKHR*);
   ```
3. As a third step, we need to find an address of any one from these functions:

   ```
    #define VK_CREATE_MACOS_SURFACE_MVK "vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK"
    #define VK_CREATE_METAL_SURFACE_EXT "vkCreateMetalSurfaceEXT"

    // In my case it's `vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK`, so I will call this variant
    auto address = (PFN_vkCreateMacOSSurfaceMVK)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(instance, VK_CREATE_MACOS_SURFACE_MVK);
   ```
4. Profit!

**P.S.** All code above it's mostly a copy-pasta from GLFW, so you can always learn more about it researching GLFW's source code. Unfortunately, I am a noobie in C++ and if you are too, I hope this code fragment will save several hours of your time and few cups of coffee.

**UPD**

I've suddenly realised that `vulkan_metal.h` and `vulkan_macos.h` are build-in interface implementations for these extensions.

Answer (score 0):

you may just need define a macro `VK_USE_PLATFORM_MACOS_MVK` before include <vulkan/vulkan.h>, then <vulkan/vulkan_macos.h> will be include automatically.

note: it's recommended to define `VK_USE_PLATFORM_METAL_EXT` witch support both ios and macos, instead of `VK_USE_PLATFORM_IOS_MVK` or `VK_USE_PLATFORM_MACOS_MVK`.